# Dynamic Compiling of XAML - Linq Error

Tags: c#, linq, workflow-foundation

I have an XAML as String which i compile and then execute.

```
DynamicActivity workflowActivity = (DynamicActivity)ActivityXamlServices.Load(new StringReader(xaml));
```

This workflow has a Person object (Type: Namespace Workflow.Model.Person) as an input, so i pass the parameters and execute it.

```
Dictionary<String,Object> parameters = new Dictionary<String,Object>();

Workflow.Model.Person person = new Workflow.Model.Person();
person.FirstName = "John";

parameters["Person"] = person;

WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(workflowActivity, parameters);
```

I get the following exception:

[System.ArgumentException] = {"Property 'System.String FirstName' is not defined for type Workflow.Model.Person'"}

The error is thrown by System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression expression, PropertyInfo property).

I have tried many things without success. If i remove the access of property FirstName inside the workflow, it executes properly. Following advice i added the import of the references but it didn't work:

```
VisualBasicSettings.Default.ImportReferences.Add(new VisualBasicImportReference()
{
    Assembly = typeof(Person).Assembly.FullName,
    Import = typeof(Person).Namespace
});
```

Any input is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. The DLL containing the class Person was loaded two times into the AppDomain. So the compiled XAML was referencing a diferent instance of the same type and as such throwing this error.